# VirtualBox shutting down without warning

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, xubuntu

I have searched this and thing seems to relate directly to what I am experiencing.  I am running VirtualBox 5.1.26 on Mac OS X 10.10.5. My Guest is Xubuntu 16.04.  I am noticing that whenever I am away from the VM for a bit of time (it doesn't seem like much, maybe 10 mins?), the VM dies or shuts down.

I do not know why this is the case. I can't see any options with VirtualBox to disable this behavior and I have display properties on Xubuntu set to never go blank, to sleep, or to shut down.

Has anybody else run into this behavior and found a solution? It is very annoying; if I step away from my machine I need to save state or else it will die and I don't want to spend the time it takes to restart a 30+ minute build.

edit 1:

- Nothing in the log file really jumps out to me (looking at the last 50 lines). then again, I am not necessarily sure what I am looking for.
- This behavior happens when I am even using the machine, but having VirtualBox in the background
- A fresh installation makes no difference. I should also note that it happens with every VM I install (it happens with CentOS 7 too, but I am mostly using Xubuntu 16.04 right now)

Comment: Does the logs that exist on the guest os hold any clues?  Are you perhaps running into a host os configuration problem (i.e. it is attempting to enter a low power mode).  Does a fresh guest installation of Xubuntu exhibit this problem?  Update your question with this information.

Comment: Edit 1 addresses these questions.